# glTexImage3D throws error 1282 (invalid operation)

Tags: c++, c, opengl, textures

I am trying to upload volumetric data as a 3D texture via OpenGL. However, when specifying the formats and data itself through `glTexImage3D`, an GL_INVALID_OPERATION error is thrown.

The code (including the debugging code I added to find out where the error was comming from) is the following:

```
void Texture3D::upload()
{
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glGenTextures(1, &_textureId);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, _textureId);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 6, GL_R8, _width, _height, _depth);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_R8, _width, _height, _depth, 0,  GL_RED,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D);

  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;
  }
```

I thought it might be an `GL_INVALID_VALUE` for any of the format, internal format, or pixel format I am specifying in the glTexImage3D, however I have checked with the documentation of [glTexImage3D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage3D.xhtml) and everything seems correct.

I have created a minimal, verifiable example (using GLFW and GLEW)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow * _window = nullptr;
unsigned int _textureId = GL_INVALID_VALUE;

void initGLFWContext()
{
  if (!glfwInit())
    {
      std::cerr << "GLFW: Couldnt initialize" << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 

    _window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 1024, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!_window)
    {
      std::cerr << "GLFW Error: Couldnt create window" << std::endl;
      glfwTerminate();
      exit(-1);
    }

    //glfwSetKeyCallback(_window, kbCb);
    //glfwSetCursorPosCallback(_window, mmCb);
    //glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(_window, mCb);
    //glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(_window, resizeCb);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);

    glfwSetWindowPos(_window, 0, 0);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Initializes glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
      std::cerr << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
    }
}

void initOpenGL()
{
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  //glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void minimalVerifiableExample()
{
  initGLFWContext();
  initOpenGL();

  const unsigned int volSide = 256;
  const unsigned int volumeSize = volSide * volSide * volSide;
  unsigned char * volumeData = new unsigned char[volumeSize]();

  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glGenTextures(1, &_textureId);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, _textureId);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 
                 6, 
                 GL_R8, 
                 volSide, 
                 volSide, 
                 volSide);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 
               0, 
               GL_R8, 
               volSide, 
               volSide, 
               volSide, 
               0, 
               GL_RED, 
               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
               volumeData);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
  std::cout << "TEX GL ERROR: " << glGetError() << std::endl;

  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(_window))
  {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
  }

  glfwDestroyWindow(_window);
  glfwTerminate();

  delete[] volumeData;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  (void) argc;
  (void) argv;
  minimalVerifiableExample();
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
TEX GL ERROR: 0
TEX GL ERROR: 0
TEX GL ERROR: 0
TEX GL ERROR: 0
TEX GL ERROR: 1282
TEX GL ERROR: 0
```

Am I doing something wrong when uploading the texture or anywhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1282 is a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` and is caused by the combination of

```
glTexStorage3D
glTexImage3D
```

It is not allowed to recreate the storage for an immutable storage texture object. After calling `glTexStorage3D`, the texture uses immutable storage. `glTexImage3D` requests a new storage which is not allowed anymore.

If you try to upload data to the immutable storage texture object, you'll have to use `glTexSubImage3D` instead which will upload data but not request new storage.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I wrongly thought I had to use `glTexImage3D`. Cannot upvote your answer though, sorry.